# Does tar -x Extract to Current Directory or Does it Extract to the Source of the Archive?

Tags: directory, filenames, tar

Does `tar -x` by default just extract to the current directory or does it try to reproduce the original directory structure including overwriting the original source? I know I can specify a folder to extract to by using `-C directory/` but I am asking about it's default behavior.

So if I used `tar -cvpjf ~/backup.tar.bz2 /` to make a backup of my root directory and I then extract the `backup.tar.bz2` (assuming I had root privileges) from within my home directory would it recreate `/` in my home directory or would it actually try to overwrite `/`?

Comment: `tar -tf ~/backup.tar.bz2` should tell you what you want to know. Paths are relative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Historically, if the paths in the archive were absolute, then they were extracted at the absolute location referred to in the archive. Some tar implementations offer an option to convert those to relative (`/foo/bar` becomes `./foo/bar`) and some like GNU tar even make it the default.

So, in short, it depends on your tar implementation. You should look at the manual for your `tar` on your own system.

Comment: Solaris's default tar is on that does not do the conversion... Dangerous extracting things without a -t first... Things tend to get overwritten.

Comment: how can we extract to a new path instead of the absolute path of the original file?